# Check if 2 substrings are present in string bash

Tags: regex, bash

I want to check if the letters "d" and "y" are present in string `str` at the same time in any order.

If I try OR operator `|` within the regex `(d|y)` evaluates to true if "d" or "y" are in string, but if use the AND operador `&` doesn´t work and evaluates to false even
both letters exist in string.

What would be the correct way to check this?

This is what I tested so far

```
str="good day"

if [[ $str =~ (d|y) ]] # This works for OR operator
if [[ $str =~ (d&y) ]] # doesn´t work for AND operator
    then 
        echo "yes"
else 
    echo "no"
fi
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [[ $str =~ (d.*y)|(y.*d) ]]; then
```

or if you don't want to repeat the `d` and `y`:

```
if [[ $str =~ d ]] && [[ $str =~ y ]] ; then
```

Comment: Hi Ed, Excellent! thanks so much for your help. Both options work. I tested a similar expression to your second option, but I see now why didn´t work. I was trying like this `if [[ $str =~ d  && $str =~ y ]]` and like this `if [[ ($str =~ d ) &&  ($str =~ y) ]]`. Both wrong hehe